# How to do pretty OSD in Python

Tags: python

Is there a library to do pretty on screen display with Python (mainly on Linux but preferably available on other OS too) ? I know there is python-osd but it uses [libxosd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libxosd) which looks quite old. I would not call it *pretty*.

Maybe a Python binding for [libaosd](http://cia.vc/stats/project/libaosd). But I did not find any.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, xosd isn't all that old; I went to university with the original author (Andre Renaud, who is a superlative programmer).  It is quite low level, but pretty simple - xosd.c is only 1365 lines long.  It wouldn't be hard to tweak it to display pretty much anything you want.

Comment: I will agree with the OP that it isn't very pretty though. The font rendering looks pretty rough.

Comment: The point is, it's dead simple.  You can make it render any bitmap you want with minor modifications.

Comment: Is it OS independent? I'm still trying to figure if it can be installed on windows.

Comment: No, it's closely tied to X as it uses low level X libs.  You would need something using Win32 to do this on Windows.  IIRC XOSD couldn't be done with GTK which is why it uses Xlib.

Comment: Just a note - the [pyosd README](https://github.com/dzen/pyosd/blob/master/README) states: "_PyOSD is a python module for displaying text on your X display_", and it seems it cannot display for instance bitmaps - just text.

Answer (score 1):

Using PyGTK on X it's possible to scrape the screen background and composite the image with a standard Pango layout.

I have some code that does this at http://svn.sacredchao.net/svn/quodlibet/trunk/plugins/events/animosd.py. It's a bit ugly and long, but mostly straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the answer from @user79758, the `animosd.py` link in that post is no longer available, but this one still is: http://hefesto.intra.ial.sp.gov.br/share/pyshared/quodlibet/plugins/events/animosd.py ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20190711182113/http://hefesto.intra.ial.sp.gov.br/share/pyshared/quodlibet/plugins/events/animosd.py)).

Regardless, it was a part of `quodlibet` music player, which still exists in Ubuntu 18.04; I installed it with

```
sudo apt install quodlibet
```

Then, it's not exactly trivial to get a minimal example; mine is included below as `animosd_test.py`; simply run it with:

```
python2 animosd_test.py
```

You'll get this:

[image: animost_test]

`animosd_test.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

#from quodlibet.ext.events.animosd.osdwindow import OSDWindow
import sys
import os
from collections import namedtuple

from quodlibet.packages.senf import environ, argv as sys_argv
from quodlibet.cli import process_arguments, exit_

import quodlibet
try:
  # we want basic commands not to import gtk (doubles process time)
  assert "gi.repository.Gtk" not in sys.modules
  sys.modules["gi.repository.Gtk"] = None
  startup_actions, cmds_todo = process_arguments(sys_argv)
finally:
  sys.modules.pop("gi.repository.Gtk", None)

quodlibet.init()

#from quodlibet.ext.events import animosd
from quodlibet.ext.events.animosd import osdwindow
from quodlibet.ext.events.animosd.config import get_config
from quodlibet.ext.events.animosd.osdwindow import OSDWindow

from quodlibet.util import cached_property, print_exc

#~ window = OSDWindow(self.Conf, song)
#~ window.add_events(Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)
#~ window.connect('button-press-event', self.__buttonpress)
#~ window.connect('fade-finished', self.__fade_finished)
#~ self.__current_window = window

#~ window.set_opacity(0.0)
#~ window.show()
#~ window.fade_in()

from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject, GLib, Pango, PangoCairo, Gdk
from quodlibet import qltk
import cairo
from math import pi

class OSDWindowMin(Gtk.Window):

  __gsignals__ = {
    'fade-finished': (GObject.SignalFlags.RUN_LAST, None, (bool,)),
  }

  POS_X = 0.5
  """position of window 0--1 horizontal"""

  MARGIN = 50
  """never any closer to the screen edge than this"""

  BORDER = 20
  """text/cover this far apart, from edge"""

  FADETIME = 0.3
  """take this many seconds to fade in or out"""

  MS = 40
  """wait this many milliseconds between steps"""

  @cached_property
  def Conf(self):
    return get_config('animosd')

  #def __init__(self, conf, song):
  def __init__(self):
    Gtk.Window.__init__(self, Gtk.WindowType.POPUP)
    self.set_type_hint(Gdk.WindowTypeHint.NOTIFICATION)

    screen = self.get_screen()
    rgba = screen.get_rgba_visual()
    if rgba is not None:
      self.set_visual(rgba)

    #self.conf = conf
    self.conf = self.Conf
    self.iteration_source = None
    self.fading_in = False
    self.fade_start_time = 0

    mgeo = screen.get_monitor_geometry(self.conf.monitor)
    textwidth = mgeo.width - 2 * (self.BORDER + self.MARGIN)

    scale_factor = self.get_scale_factor()
    #cover_pixbuf = app.cover_manager.get_pixbuf(
    #  song, conf.coversize * scale_factor, conf.coversize * scale_factor)
    coverheight = 0
    coverwidth = 0
    #~ if cover_pixbuf:
      #~ self.cover_surface = get_surface_for_pixbuf(self, cover_pixbuf)
      #~ coverwidth = cover_pixbuf.get_width() // scale_factor
      #~ coverheight = cover_pixbuf.get_height() // scale_factor
      #~ textwidth -= coverwidth + self.BORDER
    #~ else:
      #~ self.cover_surface = None
    self.cover_surface = None

    layout = self.create_pango_layout('')
    layout.set_alignment((Pango.Alignment.LEFT, Pango.Alignment.CENTER,
                Pango.Alignment.RIGHT)[self.conf.align])
    layout.set_spacing(Pango.SCALE * 7)
    layout.set_font_description(Pango.FontDescription(self.conf.font))
    #try:
    #  layout.set_markup(pattern.XMLFromMarkupPattern(conf.string) % song)
    #except pattern.error:
    #  layout.set_markup("")
    layout.set_markup("AAAA")
    layout.set_width(Pango.SCALE * textwidth)
    layoutsize = layout.get_pixel_size()
    if layoutsize[0] < textwidth:
      layout.set_width(Pango.SCALE * layoutsize[0])
      layoutsize = layout.get_pixel_size()
    self.title_layout = layout

    winw = layoutsize[0] + 2 * self.BORDER
    if coverwidth:
      winw += coverwidth + self.BORDER
    winh = max(coverheight, layoutsize[1]) + 2 * self.BORDER
    self.set_default_size(winw, winh)

    rect = namedtuple("Rect", ["x", "y", "width", "height"])
    rect.x = self.BORDER
    rect.y = (winh - coverheight) // 2
    rect.width = coverwidth
    rect.height = coverheight

    self.cover_rectangle = rect

    winx = int((mgeo.width - winw) * self.POS_X)
    winx = max(self.MARGIN, min(mgeo.width - self.MARGIN - winw, winx))
    winy = int((mgeo.height - winh) * self.conf.pos_y)
    winy = max(self.MARGIN, min(mgeo.height - self.MARGIN - winh, winy))
    self.move(winx + mgeo.x, winy + mgeo.y)

  def do_draw(self, cr):
    if self.is_composited():
      self.draw_title_info(cr)
    else:
      # manual transparency rendering follows
      walloc = self.get_allocation()
      wpos = self.get_position()

      if not getattr(self, "_bg_sf", None):
        # copy the root surface into a temp image surface
        root_win = self.get_root_window()
        bg_sf = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32,
                       walloc.width, walloc.height)
        pb = Gdk.pixbuf_get_from_window(
          root_win, wpos[0], wpos[1], walloc.width, walloc.height)
        bg_cr = cairo.Context(bg_sf)
        Gdk.cairo_set_source_pixbuf(bg_cr, pb, 0, 0)
        bg_cr.paint()
        self._bg_sf = bg_sf

      if not getattr(self, "_fg_sf", None):
        # draw the window content in another temp surface
        fg_sf = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32,
                       walloc.width, walloc.height)
        fg_cr = cairo.Context(fg_sf)
        fg_cr.set_source_surface(fg_sf)
        self.draw_title_info(fg_cr)
        self._fg_sf = fg_sf

      # first draw the background so we have 'transparancy'
      cr.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_SOURCE)
      cr.set_source_surface(self._bg_sf)
      cr.paint()

      # then draw the window content with the right opacity
      cr.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_OVER)
      cr.set_source_surface(self._fg_sf)
      cr.paint_with_alpha(self.get_opacity())

  @staticmethod
  def rounded_rectangle(cr, x, y, radius, width, height):
    cr.move_to(x + radius, y)
    cr.line_to(x + width - radius, y)
    cr.arc(x + width - radius, y + radius, radius,
         - 90.0 * pi / 180.0, 0.0 * pi / 180.0)
    cr.line_to(x + width, y + height - radius)
    cr.arc(x + width - radius, y + height - radius, radius,
         0.0 * pi / 180.0, 90.0 * pi / 180.0)
    cr.line_to(x + radius, y + height)
    cr.arc(x + radius, y + height - radius, radius,
         90.0 * pi / 180.0, 180.0 * pi / 180.0)
    cr.line_to(x, y + radius)
    cr.arc(x + radius, y + radius, radius,
         180.0 * pi / 180.0, 270.0 * pi / 180.0)
    cr.close_path()

  @property
  def corners_factor(self):
    if self.conf.corners != 0:
      return 0.14
    return 0.0

  def draw_conf_rect(self, cr, x, y, width, height, radius):
    if self.conf.corners != 0:
      self.rounded_rectangle(cr, x, y, radius, width, height)
    else:
      cr.rectangle(x, y, width, height)

  def draw_title_info(self, cr):
    cr.save()
    do_shadow = (self.conf.shadow[0] != -1.0)
    do_outline = (self.conf.outline[0] != -1.0)

    self.set_name("osd_bubble")
    qltk.add_css(self, """
      #osd_bubble {
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
      }
    """)

    cr.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_OVER)
    cr.set_source_rgba(*self.conf.fill)
    radius = min(25, self.corners_factor * min(*self.get_size()))
    self.draw_conf_rect(cr, 0, 0, self.get_size()[0],
              self.get_size()[1], radius)
    cr.fill()

    # draw border
    if do_outline:
      # Make border darker and more translucent than the fill
      f = self.conf.fill
      rgba = (f[0] / 1.25, f[1] / 1.25, f[2] / 1.25, f[3] / 2.0)
      cr.set_source_rgba(*rgba)
      self.draw_conf_rect(cr,
                1, 1,
                self.get_size()[0] - 2, self.get_size()[1] - 2,
                radius)
      cr.set_line_width(2.0)
      cr.stroke()

    textx = self.BORDER

    if self.cover_surface is not None:
      rect = self.cover_rectangle
      textx += rect.width + self.BORDER
      surface = self.cover_surface
      transmat = cairo.Matrix()

      if do_shadow:
        cr.set_source_rgba(*self.conf.shadow)
        self.draw_conf_rect(cr,
                  rect.x + 2, rect.y + 2,
                  rect.width, rect.height,
                  0.6 * self.corners_factor * rect.width)
        cr.fill()

      if do_outline:
        cr.set_source_rgba(*self.conf.outline)
        self.draw_conf_rect(cr,
                  rect.x, rect.y,
                  rect.width, rect.height,
                  0.6 * self.corners_factor * rect.width)
        cr.stroke()

      cr.set_source_surface(surface, 0, 0)
      width, height = get_surface_extents(surface)[2:]

      transmat.scale(width / float(rect.width),
               height / float(rect.height))
      transmat.translate(-rect.x, -rect.y)
      cr.get_source().set_matrix(transmat)
      self.draw_conf_rect(cr,
                rect.x, rect.y,
                rect.width, rect.height,
                0.6 * self.corners_factor * rect.width)
      cr.fill()

    PangoCairo.update_layout(cr, self.title_layout)
    height = self.title_layout.get_pixel_size()[1]
    texty = (self.get_size()[1] - height) // 2

    if do_shadow:
      cr.set_source_rgba(*self.conf.shadow)
      cr.move_to(textx + 2, texty + 2)
      PangoCairo.show_layout(cr, self.title_layout)
    if do_outline:
      cr.set_source_rgba(*self.conf.outline)
      cr.move_to(textx, texty)
      PangoCairo.layout_path(cr, self.title_layout)
      cr.stroke()
    cr.set_source_rgb(*self.conf.text[:3])
    cr.move_to(textx, texty)
    PangoCairo.show_layout(cr, self.title_layout)
    cr.restore()

  def fade_in(self):
    self.do_fade_inout(True)

  def fade_out(self):
    self.do_fade_inout(False)

  def do_fade_inout(self, fadein):
    fadein = bool(fadein)
    self.fading_in = fadein
    now = GObject.get_current_time()

    fraction = self.get_opacity()
    if not fadein:
      fraction = 1.0 - fraction
    self.fade_start_time = now - fraction * self.FADETIME

    if self.iteration_source is None:
      self.iteration_source = GLib.timeout_add(self.MS,
          self.fade_iteration_callback)

  def fade_iteration_callback(self):
    delta = GObject.get_current_time() - self.fade_start_time
    fraction = delta / self.FADETIME

    if self.fading_in:
      self.set_opacity(fraction)
    else:
      self.set_opacity(1.0 - fraction)

    if not self.is_composited():
      self.queue_draw()

    if fraction >= 1.0:
      self.iteration_source = None
      self.emit('fade-finished', self.fading_in)
      return False
    return True

def __buttonpress(window, event):
  window.hide()
  #if self.__current_window is window:
  #  self.__current_window = None
  window.destroy()

#def __fade_finished(window, fade_in):
#  if fade_in:
#    GLib.timeout_add(self.Conf.delay, self.start_fade_out, window)
#  else:
#    window.hide()
#    if self.__current_window is window:
#      self.__current_window = None
#    # Delay destroy - apparently the hide does not quite register if
#    # the destroy is done immediately.  The compiz animation plugin
#    # then sometimes triggers and causes undesirable effects while the
#    # popup should already be invisible.
#    GLib.timeout_add(1000, window.destroy)


window = OSDWindowMin()
window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit) # must be present, else program does not exit when on-screen display window is clicked!
window.add_events(Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)
window.connect('button-press-event', __buttonpress)
#window.connect('fade-finished', self.__fade_finished)
#window.show_all#()
window.set_opacity(0.0)
window.show()
window.fade_in()
Gtk.main()
```